# What is a Dockerfile.dev and how is it different from Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have been seeing some repos with Dockerfile.dev. The contents are very similar to a regular Dockerfile.

What is the difference between these two and what is the purpose of Dockerfile.dev?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is a common practice to have seperate Dockerfiles for deployments and development systems.

You can define a non default dockerfile while building:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.dev -t devimage .
```

One image could use a compiled version of the source, and a other image could mount the /src folder into the system for live updates.

Comment: could you give us some sources that is best practise?

Comment: Interesting! where is the documentation for this?

Comment: docker help build ?

Comment: A more recent practice is to define a multi-stage Dockerfile, then use --target to choose which stage your `docker build` will complete. A  docker-compose.yaml service can also point to a particular build stage / target.  https://blog.mikesir87.io/2018/07/leveraging-multi-stage-builds-single-dockerfile-dev-prod/